# Fading between two classes in jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I would like to be able to fadeout this class

```
<h2 class="care-home-fees"><a title="Care Home Fees" href="#">Text</a></h2>
```

and fade in this

```
<h2 class="care-home-fees-over"><a title="Care Home Fees" href="#">Text</a></h2>
```

Notice there are two separate images

Here is my current markup which doesnt seem to work

```
$(document).ready(function(){  

$("h2.care-home-fees").hover( 
  function () {
    $(this).addClass("care-home-fees-over");
  },
  function () {
    $(this).removeClass("care-home-fees");
  }
);  

});
```

and the button printed before any change

```
<h2 class="care-home-fees"><a title="Care Home Fees" href="#">Text</a></h2>
```

Comment: "Notice there are two separate images". What images?

Comment: you are not using  any fade..!

Answer (score 2):

You might want `.animate()` instead of `.addClass()` or `.removeClass()`.

What you want to do with CSS classes is in JQuery UI.

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: Thanks for you help, how do i animate between classes?

Comment: See here.

http://74.125.95.132/search?q=cache:SRanyKoRtxsJ:jqueryui.com/docs/Effects/Methods+jquery+ui+animate+between+classes&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-a

The actual site is down :(

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use jQuery UI for this. I would refer you to the documentation ([here](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Effects/Methods)), but it seems to be broken at the moment. You'll want to use the `addClass` and `removeClass` methods mentioned there (not the default jQuery ones).

**Edit:** see Daniel's link!

Answer (score 0):

first you need to download jquery
i have [jquery-1.3.2.min.js](http://code.google.com/p/jqueryjs/downloads/detail?name=jquery-1.3.2.min.js), but if you want the final release [jQuery 1.4.1](http://jquery14.com/day-12/jquery-141-released)

change `<h2 class="care-home-fees"><a title="Care Home Fees" href="#">Text</a></h2>`
to

```
<h2 class="care-home-fees"><a id="j" title="Care Home Fees" href="#">Text</a></h2>
```

you have to add the jquery file in your html..as i added it below::

```
//this is the start of the head
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
// i added jquery-1.3.2.min.js file here
    <script src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
  $("h2").click(function () { 
  $(document.getElementById('j')).fadeOut("slow");
$("a:hidden:first").fadeIn("slow");
  });
  </script>

//this is the end of the head
</head>
```

i hope it works..

Comment: No it didnt work, it fades out another link on the page then straight back in again.

Comment: let "Care Home Fees" visible=false

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

         $('#wm').hover(function(){
            $('#wm .bld').stop().fadeTo(300, 0);
         }, function(){
            $('#wm .bld').stop().fadeTo(300, 1);
         });

         $('#ch').hover(function(){
            $('#ch .bld').stop().fadeTo(300, 0);
         }, function(){
            $('#ch .bld').stop().fadeTo(300, 1);
         });
});
```