# jQuery: how to fade between classes?

Tags: jquery, css, class

I need to be able to fade between classes and seamlessly transition any and all styles being applied to the element and its children. How can this be done using jQuery? I know how to add/remove classes but that is not the same as a nice transition between two drastically different colors.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176413

Comment: You can do this with jQuery UI's Transition plugin (IIRC), but I'm loath to recommend jQuery UI, but that's personal preference.

Comment: Does it have to be done with jQuery?  Most recent browsers (except, of course, IE, except for possibly the next version, IE10) support CSS transitions to some degree if you use their proprietary style rules.  Or is that the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

jQuery UI has a toggleClass function that has an argument for duration:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/toggleClass/

For example, I do this on one of my sites (fade in/out the `light` class and fade/in out the `dark` class):

```
$('body').toggleClass('light', 250).toggleClass('dark', 250);
```

Comment: that looks extremely promising. i will have to check it out. thanks!

Comment: since your answer technically achieves what I was asking, I'm giving you the credit, but my experience with the jQuery UI class animations was horrible. I ended up hacking something together that involved fading in/out layers that were positioned behind the content.

Comment: In that case, there might be a more effective way to structure your layout. Sometimes I have to iterate my plans a half-dozen times before it starts being functionally sane. :)

Comment: I wonder why this is not documented in the jQuery API http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Comment: @EdwardBlack because as the answer says, it's jQuery UI, not jQuery core.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you're trying to accomplish? [Here's the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lfeey/2/)

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="toggle" value="toggle" />
<br />
<div id="classContainer">

    <div id = "class1">

    </div>
    <div id = "class2">
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#toggle").click(function (){
    if ($("#class1").is(":visible")) {
        $("#class1").fadeOut();
        $("#class2").fadeIn();
    }
    else {
        $("#class1").fadeIn();
        $("#class2").fadeOut();
    }
 });
```

CSS:

```
#classContainer
{
    position: relative;
}

#class1, #class2
{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#class1
{
    background-color: red;
    display: none;
}

#class2
{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: this is basically what i ended up doing

Answer (score 0):

Check out the color plugin for jQuery: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color

Answer (score 0):

Try fadeIn.

```
$(".myClass").fadeIn("slow");
```

http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

Although depending on the complexity you may need jQuery UI as other have mentioned.

Comment: This will fade in the elements, not the class applied to the elements.

Comment: True, this functionality should be in jQuery core imo.