# toggleClass with delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8935372/jquery-how-to-fade-between-classes) the accepted answer claimed that it is possible to use `toggleClass` with a delay. But i did not find any information about a delay parameter on the official [jquery API website](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/).

I tried it but there is no delay after a click on the div.

```js
$("div#test").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('light', 2000).toggleClass('dark', 2000);
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px dashed black;
}
.light {
  background-color: white;
}
.dark
{
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="light" id="test">
    <p style="color:red">click here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It's part of jQueryUI, not jQuery. There's even a link in the answer to the docs: http://jqueryui.com/toggleClass/

Comment: That's not jQuery only, it's jQueryUI

Comment: I am a newbie so i don't know the difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's happening because the delay behavior is added by the jQuery UI library.

You're using only the jQuery library in your example.

[jQuery website](http://jquery.com/)

[jQuery UI website](http://jqueryui.com/)

Your example works if you include jQuery UI:

```js
$("div#test").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('light', 2000).toggleClass('dark', 2000);
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px dashed black;
}

.light {
  background-color: white;
}

.dark {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="light" id="test">
  <p style="color:red">click here</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can perform this operation with a basic timeout function :

```
$("div#test").click(function () {
    var el = $(this);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        el.toggleClass('light').toggleClass('dark');
    }, 2000);
});
```

This is more efficient than a jQuery feature ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works but unfortunattely there is no fading.
https://jsfiddle.net/dzzk8oxu/1/

Comment: @EdwardBlack The fading animation should be set in your css (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411306/css3-transition-of-background-color for example)

Answer (score 2):

The `.delay()` method allows you to delay the execution of functions that follow it in the queue. It can be used with the standard effects queue or with a custom queue, only subsequent events in a queue are delayed. for example this will not delay the no-arguments forms of `.toggleClass()` or .`show()` or `.hide()` which do not use the effects queue.

Answer (score -2):

Use it like this:

```
$("div#test").click(function() {
    $(this).delay(2000).toggleClass('light').toggleClass('dark');
});
```

Comment: Don't post an answer before testing it yourself.