# Delay the toggleClass action

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have a tab and once I click it the tab fades in. The content gets loaded in with AJAX. After the animation is done I want to load in the content. Right now the content is loading in immediately when I click the button. I tried [toggleClass with delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35434476/toggleclass-with-delay) but it didn't work.

How can I delay the content from being loaded in?
This is the HTML :

```js
$("#button-1").on("click", function() {
  $(".hidden-content-1", 2000).toggleClass("show-hidden-content", 2000);
  $(".main-page-content-1", 2000).toggleClass("hide-shown-content", 2000);
})
```

```css
#modal-1 {
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: green;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.modals {
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-duration: 1000ms;
  position: absolute;
}

.active {
  width: 100vw !important;
  height: 100vh !important;
}

.show-hidden-content {
  display: block !important;
}

.hidden-content-1 {
  display: none;
}

.hide-shown-content {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="modal-1" class="modals">
  <div class="hidden-content-1">
    <h1> TEST </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="main-page-content-1">
    <h1>TEST </h1>
  </div>
  <a id="button-1" href="template-parts/panel1.php"><input onclick="change1()" type="button" value="See More" id="button-text-1"></input>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: You can not put `input` into `a`, they are both interactive elements, and HTML forbids nesting those.

Comment: `$(".hidden-content-1",2000)` makes no sense whatsoever. The second parameter for `jQuery`/ `$` is `context`, and that needs to be a DOM Element, Document, jQuery object or selector. `2000` is neither of those.

Comment: `.toggleClass("show-hidden-content", 2000)` also makes little sense. The second parameter is a boolean, saying whether the class should be added or removed.

Comment: *I tried toggleClass with delay* - did you note in the *answer* to that question that you have to have [tag:jquery-ui]?  There's no evidence in your question that you've include jquery-ui.

Comment: The question you linked to provides both a jquery-ui answer and an answer using `setTimeout` - there's not much more we can add.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking something like:

```
$('#button-1').on('click', function () {
  setTimeout(() => {
    $('.hidden-content-1').toggleClass('show-hidden-content');
    $('.main-page-content-1').toggleClass('hide-shown-content');
  }, 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use animation-delay

```
#target {
    animation: fade-in 250ms ease-out 1s 1 normal both running;
}

@keyframes fade-in {
    0% {
        opacity:0;
    } 100% {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
```